# Array separado em php

Tags: php

Galera eu to tentando deixar separado o array porém vem tudo junto desta forma fernandohenriquelopes eu queria separar eles para que eu possa fazer múltiplos insert no banco o código está assim

```
// aqui recebe em array 

$dad = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tituloFoto', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY); 

foreach ($dad as $id => $titulos) {

$re = array( ++$id => $titulos);

print_r($re); // desta forma sai normal 

//Array ( [1] => fernadno ) Array ( [2] => rafael ) Array ( [3] => yeyeye )

// se eu tirar o print_r fica assim
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\arte-beleza\galeria-gravar.php on line 21
Array (3x)
    }
```

Quando gravo no banco apresenta somente array 3 vezes alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Você quer fazer multiplos inserts de cada item do `Array` que retornou no print_r ?

Comment: isso amigo mas consegui resolver. Onde posso colocar o resultado de como fiz?

Comment: Pode colocar aqui mesmo como resposta e marcar como resolvida.

Comment: você pode usar serialize no array para salvar no banco e unserialize para recuperar do banco, sendo assim, o array é gravado em forma de string e recuperado na forma de array, sem perder as chaves que você definiu.

Comment: @BrunoFolle gostei dessa ideia vou testar. Mesmo que tenha já resolvido é bom que aprendo coisas novas